# Bind RadiobuttonList inside DataList

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Good morning .
I search many times before posting here .
I am working on a project like a survey [Questions and Answers]
I am able to get all questions in datalist , now i am searching a way to display the answers in Radio button list inside each question .

here is page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TMConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);

        //Getting All Questions

        SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Question ", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dr.Fill(ds, "Qs");
        OuterDataList.DataSource = ds.Tables["Qs"];
        OuterDataList.DataBind();
    }
```

here is page body

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h1>Test Page</h1>
    <asp:DataList ID="OuterDataList" RunAt="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <h4><%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Question") %></h4>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
 </form>
```

i dont know how to bind radiobuttonlist and group the answers .
note : the common column between Question table and Answer table is Question_id

Comment: are you displaying the answers or trying to allow users to record their answers? Does the table  "Qs" contain a column with a bit value?

Comment: sorry Trevor , i don't understand what do you mean .
but look , Qs table has [ Qid , Question ] only 
i will make another SQLDATAAdapter to get the data from Answer table based on Question ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firt will make a template like below.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataList1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
DataKeyField="QuestionID" onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Question") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RadioButtonList1">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

After that using DataList1_ItemDataBound you can bind your answers.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1 = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
            //Get questionID here
            int QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "QuestionID"));
            //pass Question ID to your DB and get all available options for the question
            //Bind the RadiobUttonList here
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1000000000 thanks seminda :) ,  it works
but we have to add  e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem also to display all answers for all questions 
thank you :)