# how can I bind data randomly into a radiobuttonlist asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on building a form. I need to show my questions and then to show 3 answers [which they're columns in the same table] in a `radiobuttonlist`.

I tried binding the data automatically to the `Datalist`.

And then to check If the correct Answer is checked ... if it's not I need to show an error

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1t" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" onselectedindexchanged="DataList1t_SelectedIndexChanged1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("TheQus") %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RadioButtonList1">
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Databasegeometreyeh.accdb" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 4 Qus.ID, Qus.TheQus, Qus.CorrectAns, Qus.Ans2, Qus.Ans3 FROM  EkhtbrNafsk INNER JOIN Qus ON EkhtbrNafsk.ID = Qus.Type  WHERE  Qus.Type= 1  order By rnd(Qus.ID)"></asp:AccessDataSource>
```

and the Code behind is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DataList1t.Visible = false;

    //DataTable QusTri = DAL.SelectFromTable("SELECT TOP 4 Qus.TheQus FROM  EkhtbrNafsk INNER JOIN Qus ON EkhtbrNafsk.ID = Qus.Type  WHERE  Qus.Type=" + 1 + " order By rnd(Qus.ID)");
    //DataList1t.DataSource = QusTri;
    //DataList1t.DataBind();

    //DataList1r.Visible = false;

    //DataTable Qusrepoe = DAL.SelectFromTable("SELECT TOP 4 Qus.TheQus FROM  EkhtbrNafsk INNER JOIN Qus ON EkhtbrNafsk.ID = Qus.Type  WHERE Qus.Type= " + 2 + " order By rnd(Qus.ID)");
    //DataList1r.DataSource = Qusrepoe;
    //DataList1r.DataBind();


    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable t1 = DAL.SelectFromTable("select * from [EkhtbrNafsk]");
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "TypeTest";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        DropDownList1.DataSource = t1;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DataList1t.Visible = false;
        DataList1r.Visible = false;
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        DataList1t.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2")
        DataList1r.Visible = true;
}
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1 = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");

        int QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ID"));
        DataTable dt = DAL.SelectFromTable("SELECT Qus.ID, Qus.CorrectAns, Qus.Ans2, Qus.Ans3 FROM  EkhtbrNafsk INNER JOIN Qus ON EkhtbrNafsk.ID = Qus.Type  WHERE  Qus.ID=" + QuestionID);

        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[0][2].ToString());//Bind the RadiobUttonList here


    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any approach to what you defined in the question.

Comment: @Shaharyar Because I really have no Idea how to do it

Comment: where is the `radiobuttonlist`?

Comment: does this work for you @AseelAssadi?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614092/bind-radiobuttonlist-inside-datalist

Comment: @Sushil Almost there ... I still have a problem using the code there ...

Comment: @Sushil the problem is that i get radiobuttonlist filled the first row the second no the third yes fourth no ,,,

Comment: can you please share your code @AseelAssadi?

Comment: you there @AseelAssadi? were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: I think, if I am reading your question correctly, the fact that your question and the answers to the question are in the same table is a much, much bigger design issue and one of the reasons why you cannot accomplish what you are trying to do. What is your rationale for not providing a separate answers table using the question ID as a FK?

Comment: @AseelAssadi I am assuming that your radiobuttons are still not getting populated? can you please share some sample data from your datatable and your output with this current code?

Comment: @Sushil The radioButtonList is getting filled but not in each row like ... 

if the firs Question is what have you done today ?

1- Pasta
2- Pizza
3- Cornflakes 

and the Secound one is what time you go out for a walk ?

here no radiobuttonlist is shown 

I edited the code you can see it after editing

Comment: @DevMode I think I should use one more table that contains the Question ID with the Correct Answer ... and in the original table to manually random the answers ... I think that is the only solution for my problem

Comment: this is because you're not writing any code for alternating item. can you try `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)`?

Comment: did this work @AseelAssadi?

Comment: No ... I tried to recreate the tables and reorder the connections so that's how it worked :\ @Sushil

Comment: oh. at least you got it working yourself. sorry couldn't be of much help.

Comment: Its ok ... anyways ... thanks :) @Sushil

Comment: you're most welcome @AseelAssadi. Can you please add me on LinkedIn?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = DAL.SelectFromTable("SELECT Qus.ID, Qus.CorrectAns, Qus.Ans2, Qus.Ans3 FROM EkhtbrNafsk ORDER BY rand() INNER JOIN Qus ON EkhtbrNafsk.ID = Qus.Type  WHERE  Qus.ID=" + QuestionID );
```

Comment: I tried it .. it's not working ... there is something wrong with the SQL Statement and I think it's the Random